# Selecionar colunas sem nome específico

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-excel, oledb

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# que consome dados de uma planilha e, em dado momento, preciso de uma string de consulta que vai alimentar uma variável.

Por exemplo:

```
strComando1 = "SELECT TOP 2 ColunaGenerica1, ColunaGenerica2 FROM ["+ planilha +"]";
```

Queria saber se é possível e como posso fazer pra consumir dados das duas primeiras colunas, por exemplo, sem especificar o nome delas, uma vez em que o nome das colunas podem variar de acordo com a importação do usuário.

Provider e conexão:

```
    private static OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection();

    strConexao = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0\"", caminhoArquivo);
    conexao.ConnectionString = strConexao;

    private static DataTable tabelaDeSaida;
```

Comment: Qual provider está usando ? coloca o código da conexão... comando... etc

Comment: Feito. Adicionei informações sobre o provider e a conexão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando:

```
DataTable dtCols = conexao.GetSchema("Columns");
```

ou

```
DataTable dtCols = conexao.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new Object[] {null, null, "NomeDaTabela", null});
```

Ele irá retornar um `DataTable`, que tem as seguintes colunas (entre outras):

```
TABLE_NAME
COLUMN_NAME
ORDINAL_POSITION
```

A partir daí, basta pegar a coluna que você quer, da tabela que quiser e montar a query.

Exemplo:

```
conexao.Open();

DataTable dtCols = conexao.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new Object[] { null, null, "tabela$", null });

DataRow[] rs = dtCols.Select("ORDINAL_POSITION <= 2");

string query = "Select ";
foreach (DataRow r in rs)
{
    query+= r["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString()+ ",";
}

query = query.Remove(query.Length-1);

query += " From tabela$ where 1=1;";

MessageBox.Show(query);
```

Resultado:

> `Select coluna1,coluna2 From tabela$ where 1=1;`

Comment: Pensei em uma solução parecida, mas como pegar a primeira e a segunda colunas? Esse é o ponto

Comment: @rLinhares coloquei um exemplo =], e começa pelo 1